I'm looking for a certain mecha anime
All I remember about it was that the pilots of these robots would stand on a platform that was their cockpit, and they wore this latex-looking body suit that they put on by inching up through the platform after getting in their robot.  They didn't use handles, buttons or joysticks to control their robot - the bodysuit synced up the pilot's movement to the mecha, so they'd throw a punch together. If a limb was torn off, that segment would flash red on the bodysuit to alert the pilot.
There was an episode where the (possible) main character was escaping a max-security prison on a mountain - or maybe a volcano? Does this ring any bells? I browsed over all the Gundam series, and it doesn't look like any of those. I think it was on Toonami or Adult swim years ago.

maybe check the list of all shows aired on these channels around these years

I'm going to take a widely correct guess that you are referring to Mobile Fighter G Gundam, the not very Gundam Gundam series. More like Street Fighter meets Gundam. Unlike the traditional Gundam series, the G Gundam's comically stereotypically offensive Gundams (Including America's Football Gundam and Mexico's Tequila Cactus Gundam) use the Mobile Trace System, where a skin tight suit is placed on the operator, and their every movement is copied by their Gundam.



One of the characters, Argo Gulskii, is a prisoner of his country, Neo Russia, forced to stay in the Neo Russian Prison, and pilot the Russian Hat wearing Bolt Gundam. Argo, in a fight with the main character Domon, the Japanese Gundam's God/Burning/G Gundam pilot, disables Burning's arm, causing Domon's suit to glow red in the matching arm.
The show was dubbed and aired on Cartoon Network/Toonami in 2002.

Dang, my eyes. That's Bat nipple levels of uncomfortably tight close ups. Rain got it even worse.

Yeah, I did some more digging after asking this, and I don't know how I skipped over G Gundam.  I thought it came along later than '02, for whatever reason, and looked for stuff closer to '07.  Thanks for reaffirming my dingusness.
